# Tornado / both-sided horizontal bar-plot in R with chart axes crosses at a given value (instead of crossing at zero)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to plot a tornado chart (both-sided horizontal bar plot) in R for deterministic sensitivity analysis for which I have tried a few codes but not getting the desired output.

I would like to achieve: -

1. The plot should be arranged in descending order of sensitive parameters (i.e. most wide interval should be represented at the top of the chart - to get sensitivity we first calculate the absolute difference in lower bound value and upper bound value which I named "UL_Difference" in my data frame code).
2. The centre should not be at zero but should be at a given value, called the 'base case' or the core/final result of my result table (on which we want to check the impact of varying fixed parameters using lower bound and upper bound values of parameters and generating core result for lower bound and upper bound value). Example code in Excel VBA is
3. The plot should have heading "Tornado Plot for Drug A vs P".

I have tried many codes. Below is an example which is giving me a tornado plot but not exactly what I wanted to generate from R.

```
Base_Result <- results.table[5,4] # Base/Core result (which I have not used in my codes below yet)

Drug_AP <- seq(1, 48, 4)
D_AP <- data.frame(OWSA[Drug_AP,]) # OWSA[] is a 10x3 matrix with 'Lower_Bound', 'Upper_Bound' and Absolute Difference of the LB and UB termed as 'UL_Difference' (row names are parameters)
DSA_Drug_AP <- D_AP[order(D_AP$UL_Difference, decreasing = T),] # Ordering the data.frame above in Descending order of 'UL_Difference'
cat("DSA Table: Drug A vs P \n")
library(formattable)
print(accounting(as.matrix(DSA_Drug_AP), digits = 0, format = "f", big.mark = ","), right = T) # Just printing the above data.frame
```

I tried the below codes for plotting the tornado: -

(I'm not sure whether I should make the below data frame, maybe this is one of the reasons I'm not getting the desired output)

```
dat <- data.frame(Group = c(rep("Lower_Bound", 12), rep("Upper_Bound", 12)), 
                  Parameters = rep(rownames(DSA_Drug_AP), 2), 
                  UL = c(-DSA_Drug_AP[,1], DSA_Drug_AP[,2]))
```

(Finally, I plotted the above data frame using "ggplot" as shown below)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = Parameters, y = UL, fill = Group)) + 
    coord_flip() + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "identity", width = 0.525) +
    theme(legend.position="top", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, size = 10))
```

And getting the output as below: -

[image]

Below is the output that I would like to achieve (point #1 and #2 are achieved; the graph is generated from excel).

[image]

```
# Also, the data I'm using is shown below: -

Base_Result <- 9,504  # Value of results.table[5,4] on which I get 'lower' and 'upper' limit values below (and want tornado with the origin at this base_result).

# My data.frame "D_AP" will look like (I just renamed my parameters to 1(to)12)

           Lower_Bound  Upper_Bound UL_Difference
Parameter_01     8,074      11,181   3,108 
Parameter_02     8,177      11,007   2,831 
Parameter_03     8,879      10,188   1,308 
Parameter_04     4,358      18,697   14,339 
Parameter_05     9,073      10,087   1,013 
Parameter_06     12,034      7,572   4,462 
Parameter_07     11,357      7,933   3,423 
Parameter_08     9,769       9,202   567 
Parameter_09     8,833      10,403   1,570 
Parameter_10     13,450      4,219   9,231 
Parameter_11     10,691      7,915   2,776 
Parameter_12     10,036      8,792   1,244 

# Once, I did sort in descending order then it will be data.frame "DSA_Drug_AP" as below: -

            Lower_Bound Upper_Bound UL_Difference
Parameter_04     4,358      18,697   14,339 
Parameter_10     13,450      4,219   9,231 
Parameter_06     12,034      7,572   4,462 
Parameter_07     11,357      7,933   3,423 
Parameter_01     8,074      11,181   3,108 
Parameter_02     8,177      11,007   2,831 
Parameter_11     10,691      7,915   2,776 
Parameter_09     8,833      10,403   1,570 
Parameter_03     8,879      10,188   1,308 
Parameter_12     10,036      8,792   1,244 
Parameter_05     9,073      10,087   1,013 
Parameter_08     9,769       9,202   567 

# Please note that I need to plot the 1st and 2nd column of values 
# (shown in above table in order of 3rd column as a tornado plot).
# The parameter-## names will come to the left vertical line of plot.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried doing this some time ago using `geom_bar()` and it was not fun. `geom_bar()` by default stacks the columns having zero as the reference. I had to create empty parts in the columns to get (kind of) the effect that I wanted.

A better way to do it is using `geom_rect()`. You just need to massage your data frame a little bit in order to get the `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` aesthetics it requires (way less work than trying to go around the issues with `geom_bar()`)

<s>Since you did not post your data set, I created a very simple one. But hopefully the structure is close enough to yours</s>

---

**EDIT**: I changed the code to include the data frame in your example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

# this is throwing some warnings in my computer, but it is reading the data frame correctly
df <- '
Parameter Lower_Bound Upper_Bound UL_Difference
Parameter01 8074 11181 3108 
Parameter02 8177 11007 2831 
Parameter03 8879 10188 1308 
Parameter04 4358 18697 14339 
Parameter05 9073 10087 1013 
Parameter06 12034 7572 4462 
Parameter07 11357 7933 3423 
Parameter08 9769 9202 567 
Parameter09 8833 10403 1570 
Parameter10 13450 4219 9231 
Parameter11 10691 7915 2776 
Parameter12 10036 8792 1244
' %>% read_table2()

# original value of output
base.value <- 9504

# get order of parameters according to size of intervals
# (I use this to define the ordering of the factors which I then use to define the positions in the plot)
order.parameters <- df %>% arrange(UL_Difference) %>%
  mutate(Parameter=factor(x=Parameter, levels=Parameter)) %>%
  select(Parameter) %>% unlist() %>% levels()

# width of columns in plot (value between 0 and 1)
width <- 0.95

# get data frame in shape for ggplot and geom_rect
df.2 <- df %>% 
  # gather columns Lower_Bound and Upper_Bound into a single column using gather
  gather(key='type', value='output.value', Lower_Bound:Upper_Bound) %>%
  # just reordering columns
  select(Parameter, type, output.value, UL_Difference) %>%
  # create the columns for geom_rect
  mutate(Parameter=factor(Parameter, levels=order.parameters),
         ymin=pmin(output.value, base.value),
         ymax=pmax(output.value, base.value),
         xmin=as.numeric(Parameter)-width/2,
         xmax=as.numeric(Parameter)+width/2)

# create plot
# (use scale_x_continuous to change labels in y axis to name of parameters)
png(width = 960, height = 540)
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(data = df.2, 
            aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=xmax, xmin=xmin, fill=type)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(), legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = base.value) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1:length(order.parameters)), 
                     labels = order.parameters) +
  coord_flip()
dev.off()
```

[image: Here is my resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks, Kikoralston for your answer to the post. I realized that I should have provided some dummy data which also helped in adding more clarity to what output I have and wanted to plot. Thanks for your codes, but I checked that I don't have any input.value for which I am getting output.value. But rather I have only the output (lower bound and upper bound) values. I have edited my question and added the data along with base_result (the origin of the tornado). I hope it would be helpful for you to modify the codes so I can get the required output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user11334975: Can you give more details about these values in your data set, please? This is how I understand tornado plots. You have a `Base_result` value that you simulated using your model with typical values for all your parameters. Then you pick one param. (e.g. `Parameter-01`) and change its value by -10% and +10% (for example). This gives you two new values for your result (`Lower_Bound` and `Upper_Bound`). The way i see it  `Base_Result` should be in the range [`Lower bound`, `Upper bound`]. But this is not the case in your data frame. I am interpreting something incorrectly?

Comment: Great! You are on the right way/track in understanding the problem. Thanks for pointing the error. In order to maintain confidentiality, I had modified the data too much that even I have not noticed that base_result is now getting out of LB and UB values (which is not possible). I have edited the data in my question for a scenario run.

Comment: Thank you so much Kikoralston! I finally get the required output. Also, since 'Parameter' was not a part of the output dataset so I used `df <- data.frame(rownames_to_column(D_AP, var = "Parameter"))` to get the required column 'Parameter'.  Could you let me know: 1. How the `library(tidyverse)` was useful? I get the result without loading it (though installed in my R). 2.  Also, I use 'RStudio' & noticed that the image is getting saved in my directory with specified height & width but parameter names etc. are quite blurred, but if I save it using 'export' (any size) under plots then is clear.

Comment: I am glad I could help! Regarding your questions: 1) I use `tidyverse` just to use the `read_table2()`function and be able to read the string as a data frame (in your case you probably deleted this part); 2) (see next comment)

Comment: 2) I used the `png()` function to save the plot as a png file (instead of plotting it to the R studio plot window). The png function allows you to define the size/resolution of the file (in my case 960x540 pixels). The export function in R studio probably uses other settings when saving the plot as a file. There are other important settings you can play with (e.g.`point size` and `res`). I admit that I don't dominate this part very well and I always do a try & error approach until I get the look I want. A good resource for this is [this link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Output_to_a_file)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function to generate tornado plots using ggplot2::geom_col() along with some usage examples. Hope it helps....

```
# Tornado Plot using ggplot2(), 2019/05/19.
# See Wikipedia: ["Tornado diagram"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_diagram).

library( magrittr )
library( tidyverse )

# Function tornado_plot() produces a "tornado plot" given the sensitivity
# analysis results in data_frame df. It plots green bars indicating the levels
# of the response variable when each **x input variable** is moved to its maximum
# level while holding all other variables constant.  Similarly, the red bars are
# the outputs when each **x input variable** is moved to its minimum value while
# holding all other variables constant. The input variable to which the output
# is most sensitive is shown at the top of the plot. And the bars are stacked
# from most sensitive to least sensitive, fancifully yielding the shape of a
# tornado.
tornado_plot <-
  function(
    df,
    var_names_col,
    min_level_col,
    min_output_col,
    max_level_col,
    max_output_col,
    base_level_col,
    baseline_output,
    title_str      = "Tornado Plot",
    subtitle_str   = "",
    caption_str    = "",
    ylab_str       = "output",
    baseline_label = "",
    scale_breaks   = NULL,
    limits         = NULL
  ) {
    # + The argument df must be a tidyverse::tibble with columns referred to by all of the
    #   other arguments having "col" in their names.
    # + The var_names_col argument must be an unquoted column name that contains characters
    #    naming the variables that were varied in the sensitivity analysis.
    # + The level column arguments -- min_level_col, max_level_col and
    #   base_level_col -- must be unquoted column names that contain characters to be
    #   used in forming labels for each variable bar of the plot.
    # + The output column arguments -- min_output_col and max_output_col -- must
    #   be unquoted column names that contain numerical values to be plotted as the
    #   extents of the bars in the plot.
    # + The baseline_output argument is the numeric value of the output (response) variable
    #   produced by setting all of the variables to their base levels.

    var_names_col  <- enquo( var_names_col )
    min_level_col  <- enquo( min_level_col )
    max_level_col  <- enquo( max_level_col )
    base_level_col <- enquo( base_level_col )
    min_output_col <- enquo( min_output_col )
    max_output_col <- enquo( max_output_col )

    have_custom_y_breaks <- !any( is.null(scale_breaks) )

    # Create a generic tibble as the data source for plotting.
    # Sorts variables from the one to which the output was least sensitive
    # to the one to which the output was most sensitive.
    # Then creates labels for each variable capturing the min, base, and max
    # levels of that variable.
    # Finally, it centers all outputs around the baseline output so thta the
    # ggplot2::geom_col() function can still work with zero-based bars.
    plt_df <- df %>% 
      mutate(del = abs(!!max_output_col - !!min_output_col) ) %>% 
      arrange(del) %>% 
      mutate(
        names = sprintf(
          "%s\n(min=%s; base=%s; max=%s)",
          !!var_names_col,
          !!min_level_col,
          !!base_level_col,
          !!max_level_col
        ),
        names = factor(names,names),
        min   = !!min_output_col,
        max   = !!max_output_col
      ) %>% 
      dplyr::select(names,min,max) %>% 
      gather( key = Level, value = output, -names) %>% 
      mutate( output = output - baseline_output, Level = factor(Level,c("min","max")) ) #%T>% print()

    # Generate the tornado plot.
    plt <- plt_df %>% 
      {
        ggplot(., aes( fill = Level, x = names, y = output )) + 
          geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 1, size = 2, color = "darkgray") +
          geom_col( alpha = 0.4, width = 0.98) + 
          coord_flip() + #*** NOTE THE COORDINATE FLIP ***
          geom_text(aes(y = 0, label = names), size = 4, fontface = "bold" ) +
          scale_x_discrete( expand = expand_scale(add = 1 ) ) +
          scale_fill_manual(values = c(min = "red", max = "green") ) +
          ylab( ylab_str ) +
          theme( # **Hmmm, references the ACTUAL plotted (post-flipped) x-y axes. **
            axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), # Remove horizontal grid lines
            panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x  = element_text( size = 14 ),
            axis.title.x = element_text( size = 16 ),
            title        = element_text( size = 18 ),
            legend.position = "bottom"
          ) +
          labs( title = title_str, subtitle = subtitle_str, caption = caption_str )
      }
    # Set the pre-flipped y-axis (which gets flipped to be the x-axis in the final plot).
    if( !is.null(limits) ){
      y_limits = limits
    } else {
      y_limits = c(-max(abs(plt_df$output)),max(abs(plt_df$output)))
    }
    if( have_custom_y_breaks ){
      plt <- plt + scale_y_continuous(
        limits = y_limits,
        breaks = scale_breaks,
        labels = names(scale_breaks)
      )
    } else {
      plt <- plt + scale_y_continuous(
        limits = y_limits,
        labels = function(x) baseline_output + x
      )
    }
    # Add the baseline output label, if any
    if(baseline_label != ""){
      return(
        plt + 
          geom_label(
            data = tibble( x = 0.25, y = 0, label = baseline_label),
            mapping = aes( x = x, y = y, label = label),
            fontface = "bold",
            show.legend = FALSE,
            inherit.aes = FALSE
          )
      )
    } else {
      return( plt )
    }
  }

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

# USAGE EXAMPLE:
# Hypothetical Investment Strategy Analysis:
# These are data from a sensitivity analysis on an investment strategy that invests in an
# an S&P 500 index fund and a "safety" value-store (a 0%-real-return investment); 
# protecting winnings from market with transfer to safety when strategy criteria are met. 
# Disregards taxes and fees. Real values (i.e., inflation-adjusted).
sensitivity_df <- tribble(
  ~variable,                            ~min,  ~base,   ~max, ~Total_at_min, ~Total_base, ~Total_at_max,             ~Time_period,
  "Start Value",                           0,   2000, 100000,        239600,      245900,        554800, "start: 1980, end: 2005",
  "Monthly Investment",                    0,    500,   1000,          6300,      245900,        485600, "start: 1980, end: 2005",
  "Allocation to Safety",                  0,    0.3,    0.5,        277800,      245900,        224700, "start: 1980, end: 2005",
  "Annual Increase in Mo. Investment",     0,   0.01,   0.03,        222700,      245900,        303800, "start: 1980, end: 2005",
  "Protection Rate",                       0, 0.0025,   0.03,        310300,      245900,        199500, "start: 1980, end: 2005",

  "Start Value",                           0,   2000, 100000,        174300,      175900,        253300, "start: 1910, end: 1935",
  "Monthly Investment",                    0,    500,   1000,          1600,      175900,        350100, "start: 1910, end: 1935",
  "Allocation to Safety",                  0,    0.3,    0.5,        177700,      175900,        174600, "start: 1910, end: 1935",
  "Annual Increase in Mo. Investment",     0,   0.01,   0.03,        155600,      175900,        227100, "start: 1910, end: 1935",
  "Protection Rate",                       0, 0.0025,   0.03,        171800,      175900,        176000, "start: 1910, end: 1935"
) %>%  # Add x-input level labels (overwriting reals min, base, max with character values through mutate_at()).
  mutate_at(vars(contains("Total")), ~{100*round(./100)}) %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars( min, base, max), 
    ~ { 
      ifelse(
        abs(.) >= 1000,
        paste0("$",formatC(.,big.mark = ",",format = "f",digits = 0)),
        sprintf(
          c( "$%.0f", "$%.0f", "%.0f%%", "%.1f%%", "%.2f%%" ), 
          . * c(1,1,100,100,100)
        )
      )
    } 
  )

# Generate the tornado plot with generic labeling and axis.
sensitivity_df %>%
  filter( grepl("1980.+2005", Time_period ) ) %>%
  tornado_plot(
    var_names_col   = variable,
    min_level_col   = min,
    min_output_col  = Total_at_min,
    max_level_col   = max,
    max_output_col  = Total_at_max,
    base_level_col  = base,
    baseline_output = .$Total_base[[1]]
  ) %>% print()


# Generate the tornado plot with customized labeling and axis.
scl_limits = c(0, 6.0e5 )
sensitivity_df %>%
  filter( grepl("1980.+2005", Time_period ) ) %>%
  tornado_plot(
    var_names_col   = variable,
    min_level_col   = min,
    min_output_col  = Total_at_min,
    max_level_col   = max,
    max_output_col  = Total_at_max,
    base_level_col  = base,
    baseline_output = .$Total_base[[1]],
    title_str       = "Sensitivity of Total Value to Strategy Variables",
    subtitle_str    = sprintf( "Time period %s", .$Time_period[[1]] ),
    caption_str     = "Assuming S&P 500 index & 0%-real-return 'safe harbor'",
    ylab_str        = "Total Value",
    baseline_label  = paste0("Base Case:\n$",format(100*round(.$Total_base[[1]]/100,0),big.mark = ",")),
    scale_breaks    = setNames(
      seq(min(scl_limits), max(scl_limits), 1e5) - .$Total_base[[1]], 
      paste0("$",formatC(
        seq(min(scl_limits), max(scl_limits), 1e5),big.mark = ",",format = "f",digits = 0)
      )
    ),
    limits          = scl_limits - .$Total_base[[1]]
  ) %>% print()

# Generate the tornado plot for another time period, with scaling
# to be comparable with the first time period.
sensitivity_df %>%
  filter( grepl("1910.+1935", Time_period ) ) %>%
  tornado_plot(
    var_names_col   = variable,
    min_level_col   = min,
    min_output_col  = Total_at_min,
    max_level_col   = max,
    max_output_col  = Total_at_max,
    base_level_col  = base,
    baseline_output = .$Total_base[[1]],
    title_str       = "Sensitivity of Total Value to Strategy Variables",
    subtitle_str    = sprintf( "Time period %s", .$Time_period[[1]] ),
    caption_str     = "Assuming S&P 500 index & 0%-real-return 'safe harbor'",
    ylab_str        = "Total Value",
    baseline_label  = paste0("Base Case:\n$",format(100*round(.$Total_base[[1]]/100,0),big.mark = ",")),
    scale_breaks    = setNames(
      seq(min(scl_limits), max(scl_limits), 1e5) - .$Total_base[[1]], 
      paste0("$",formatC(
        seq(min(scl_limits), max(scl_limits), 1e5),big.mark = ",",format = "f",digits = 0)
      )
    ),
    limits          = scl_limits - .$Total_base[[1]]
  ) %>% print()
```

[Generic tornado plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDOQR.png)

[Tornado plot with custom labels, axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2ilR.png)

[Tornado plot w/custom labels and on same scale as previous one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW2Y0.png)